# how to download file in jsp and servlet?

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

I am working on the jsp project. I have an option to download files or images. but the problem is after downloading the file it seems unsupported file format.how to solve that issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, create a simple link in your jsp page that redirects you to the servlet. instead of jpg, you can put any type of file.

```
<a href="ServletName?value=filename.jpg">Downlaod</a>
```

here is the servlet code for download any file from your web directory. Don't forget to create "files" folder in your web-pages directory and paste the file.

```
try (PrintWriter out = response.getWriter()) {
        //fetch the file name from the url
        String name = request.getParameter("value");
        //get the directory of the file.
        String path = getServletContext().getRealPath("/" + "files" + File.separator + name);
        //set the content type
        response.setContentType("APPLICATION/OCTET-STREAM");
        //force to download dialog
        response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=\"" + name + "\"");

        FileInputStream ins = new FileInputStream(path);


        int i;
        while ((i = ins.read()) != -1) {
            out.write(i);
        }
        ins.close();
        out.close();
    }
```

that's all. you can check this [Download File in jsp and servlet](https://youtu.be/_MLTr0_XXhs) youtube video for more.